# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09:07:31 AM PDT"

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I have a field in the response that is coming as time which I want to parse before adding some minutes into it. I have written the below code which results in error.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss a SSS");
        Date date = df.parse(currentTime);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
```

here, currentTime is coming in as "09:07:31 AM PDT"

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: If you want minutes, use `mm` instead of `MM` as `M` stands for `Month in year`, not `Minute in hour`

Comment: And (what I think caused the error), time zones are `Z` or `z`, not `S` (millisecond)

Comment: try using `HH:mm:ss a ZZZ` as the pattern

Comment: Thank you, the HH:mm:ss a ZZZ solved it

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime`, `ZoneId` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If there is any way at all you can avoid it, don’t rely on three or four letter time zone abbreviations. While to me PDT means Pacific Daylight Time (in North America), others may have other interpretations. In general such abbreviations are ambiguous, I think more often than not.

Comment: One of the many confusing traits of `SimpleDateFormat` is that it parses a string with no date in it into January 1, 1970. And I believe that no time zone was using Pacific Daylight Time on that date. So no matter how you look at it you are getting an inconsistent result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the right combination of letters in format, here:

```java
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa zzz");
```

You might also want to look at API docs [1].

**Note**: Parsing would work if you use the above format, but you will need the date part as well for accurate calculations. Here is an example with the current date of the current timezone of your machine used as the date part.

```java
        String recievedTime = "09:07:31 AM PDT";
        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa zzz");
        Date date = df.parse(currentDate +" " + recievedTime);
```

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Given the use of AM/PM, the format should use `hh` instead of `HH`.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime                                        // Represent a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.parse(               
    "09:07:31 AM PDT".substring( 0 , 11 ) ,      // Remove the senseless `PDT` from the input.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" )  // Define a formatting pattern to match our modified input string.
)                                                // Returns a `LocalTime` object.
.toString()                                      // Generates text in standard ISO 8601 format to represent the value of our `LocalTime` object.
```

> 09:07:31

## Avoid `Date` & `Calendar`

You are using terrible date-time classes that were bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

## `Date` class does not fit

The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment, a date with time-of-day, as seen in UTC. Your input lacks a date. So your input cannot be represented by this class.

## Time-of-day with zone makes no sense

Your input represents a time-of-day with what is a false time zone. The `PDT` likely stands for "Pacific Daylight Saving Time", to indicate whether [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is in effect or not. This is not a true time zone name. Instead a time zone name such as `America/Los_Angeles` should be used.

At any rate, the combination of a time-of-day with a time zone makes no sense. Without the context of a date, the time zone carries no meaning.

## `LocalTime`

I suggest you extract the time-of-day and ignore the `PDT`. Take the first 11 characters.

```
String input = "09:07:31 AM PDT";
String s = input.substring( 0 , 11 ); // Uses annoying zero-based index counting. So asking for first through the eleventh characters requires ( 0 , 11 ).
```

Define a formatting pattern to match our modified input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" );
```

Parse as a `LocalTime`, a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( s , f );
```

> lt.toString(): 09:07:31

## `ZonedDateTime`

For fun, let's apply a time zone to your time-of-day, and a date to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "01:59:00 AM PDT".substring( 0 , 11 ) , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" ) );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 7 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusMinutes( 5 );
System.out.println( "zdtLater = " + zdtLater );
```

We get 2:04 AM.

> zdtLater = 2020-03-07T02:04-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Change that date to the 8th.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "01:59:00 AM PDT".substring( 0 , 11 ) , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" ) );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 8 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusMinutes( 5 );
System.out.println( "zdtLater = " + zdtLater );
```

We get 3:04 AM, not 2:04 AM.

> zdtLater = 2020-03-08T03:04-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

The date is what gives meaning to that time-of-day in a time zone.

Offsets vary over time. That is the meaning of a time zone. A time zone such as `America/Los_Angeles` is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people in many regions on the west coast of North America. On March 7, 2020 the offset was eight hours behind UTC. On March 8, 2020, the offset was changed to seven hours behind UTC. At the first moment of 2 AM, the clock jumped an hour to 3 AM. The 2 AM hour never happened on the 8th as it did on the 7th.

## `OffsetTime`

The *java.time* framework does offer the [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetTime.html) class. This represents a time-of-day with an offset-from-UTC.

This class makes no sense, for the same reasons discussed above. A time-of-day with an offset but no date serves no useful purpose. I presume this was added to *java.time* merely to match the SQL-standard type `TIME WITH TIME ZONE`, in parallel with `LocalTime` matching `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. But this `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` type makes no sense in SQL. This problem is noted by others, not merely my opinion. And this is not the only senseless thing in the SQL standard.

Furthermore, your input carries a time zone (or at least a time zone was intended by the mis-use of `PDT`), not an offset. An offset is a number of hour-minutes-seconds, nothing more. A time zone is a history of changes in offset, as discussed above.

Comment: I understand the no use of PDT here, but the requirement is such that I need to display the input time as is after adding certain minutes to it. I don't have to get rid of the tiimezone else it'll be a mismatch of requirement.

Comment: @SonaliGupta You are being asked to do the impossible. Add five minutes to 01:59 on March 7, 2020 in `America/Los_Angeles` and you get 02:04. Add five minutes to 01:59 on March 8, 2020 in `America/Los_Angeles` and you get 03:04. Which is right? Without a date, adding five minutes to a time-of-day intended for the west coast of North America makes no sense. This is like exchanging a money amount between currencies without a date-time: exchange rates vary so the date-time is required. Likewise, offsets vary, so the date is required to add five minutes to a time-of-day in a particular zone.

Comment: Got your point. I can actually now see the output and understand how the times are not making sense, adding 17 minutes shows an entirely different time. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @BasilBourque - I've missed you after this answer. I hope, all is well at your end.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Well, thanks for noticing. I am cutting back on my Stack Overflow time to focus on some chores. I'll be more involved here on a later date.